# How to deserialize JSON to my custom Class

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

Im new to JSON (and not sure if its the right way to do that), my problem is to deserialize my classes, all models implements this interface:

```
public interface IPersistent
{
  object Id { get; set; }
}
```

Example of class:

```
public class ModelTest : IPersistent
{
    private int? _id;
    public object Id
    {
        get { return this._id; }
        set { this._id = (int?)value; }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Serialize method:

```
 public void SerializeData<T>(T[] data)
 {
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
                    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
                };
    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented, settings);
    //more things happen, but not affect serialized data.
 }
```

Deserialize method:

```
 public T[] DeserializeData<T>(string objCached)
 {
     var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
                    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
                }; //not sure if a need this settings, but...
     T[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(objCached, settings);  //error here.              
     return result;
 }
```

Error:

> Message=Specified cast is not valid.

objCached data:

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "Id": 1000,
    "Name": "Name 1"
  },
  {
    "$id": "2",
    "Id": 2000,
    "Name": "Name 2"
  },
  {
    "$id": "3",
    "Id": 3000,
    "Name": "Name 3"
  },
  {
    "$id": "4",
    "Id": 4000,
    "Name": "Name 4"
  }
]
```

I tried validate JSON result using:
http://json2csharp.com/

Result:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string __invalid_name__$id { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm looking for something that changes just the methods (Serialize and Deseriaize), can't change ALL my models (its a legacy without any unit test).

Comment: Looks like it happens because `Id` in `ModelTest` is an object and not an int. Do you need it to be an object?

Comment: Also you need one more field for $id which is not a valid C sharp identifier as suggested by your RootObject field name.

Comment: Yea, its an Object because some of the models cast to (long?), in rare cases its a struct.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is changing the set method of Id property. (Because `value` is *long* when read from json, which can not be casted to`int?`)

```
public class ModelTest : IPersistent
    {
        private int? _id;
        public object Id
        {
            get { return this._id; }
            set { this._id = new Nullable<int>((int)(long)value); }
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can't cast long to int, it throw an exception, but if i do:

    set { this._id = value != null ? Convert.ToInt32(value) :     (int?)null; }

It works, but i have to change all models.. thats not good, any sugestion?